# break out of find if an -exec fails

Tags: find

Is there a way to write an `find` so that it breaks if one of the `-exec` operations fails on a file?

E.g. (`javac` is conveniently used as a program that can return an exit code of 1 on some files and for no other reason):

```
$ echo "public classXX A{}" >> A.java
$ echo "public class B{}" >> B.java
$ find . -iname \*.java -exec javac {} \;
./A.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
public classXX A{}
       ^
1 error
```

In the example above, although the `exec` on the file `A.java` failed (and returned an exit code of 1), the `find` command proceeded and compiled file `B.java` as well. Is there a way to break out of `find` or should I use some form of `for` instead?

My version of find:

```
$ find -version  | head -1
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think...

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'cmd "$0" || kill $PPID' \{\} \;
```

...should do the trick for just about any `find`.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. What does the `$0` do?

Comment: `$0` is the first argument to `sh -c` (`$1` is the second one, etc.) — conventionally the name of the program being executed, but here you're executing a snippet, and passing the file name that's being processed as `$0` makes some sense (e.g. you easily see it in `ps`). There's a school of thought (which I obviously don't belong to) that states that `$0` should always be executable and you should write `sh -c 'cmd "$1" …' sh {}` or some such.

Comment: @Gilles - pretty slick. Thanks a lot. I figured it out in the car on the way to the preschool, but I had to think about it for several minutes. That's smart - I'm gonna use it. What actually clicked it over for me was an edit I remembered reading of Stephane's on one of your own posts in which he added a `find-sh` `$0` to the end of a `find` statement. This seems more useful in my opinion, though I guess it's what you're after in the long run that matters most.

Comment: It's not working for the case above. After `find . -iname \*.java -exec sh -c 'javac "${0}" || kill '$$ {} \;` file `A.java` fails and, still, file B.java gets compiled.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - I fixed it. I should've seen your comment earlier. Again, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

At least with GNU `find` you can use:

```
find ... -exec ... -o -quit
```

Comment: I seem to have trouble making it clear where the exec stops and the -o starts. Both `find . -iname \*.java -exec javac {}  -o -quit \;` and `find . -iname \*.java -exec javac {} \; -o -quit \;` fail (in different ways)

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus `\;` is needed at the and of `-exec` (i.e. before `-o -quit` in this case) but may be nowhere else.

Comment: Using `-exec ... -o -quit` does not work for me. It does not process _any_ files. However this line works: `find . -iname \*.java -not -exec javac '{}' \; -quit`: `-quit` is called if `-exec` is false, ie. returns with non-zero.

Comment: `find . -iname \*.java -exec javac {} \; -o -quit`, too, fails to process any files. Strangely, `find . -iname \* -exec echo 'foo' \; -o -quit` *does* "process" the files.

Comment: `find ... \( -exec ... -o -quit \)` will prevent quit from running when something in the first `...` evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

Consult your `find` manual.  @Hauke's answer motivated me to look and QNX's find has an `-abort` option that seems similar to the GNU `-quit` option.  It works for me provided I use `\(` and `\)` to group expressions:

```
find . -mtime -4 -name <pattern> \( -exec my_cmd {} \; -o  -abort \)
```

Note: without the parens, it aborts on the first file.

Answer (score 0):

```
find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0
```

---

```
find . -name '*'   \( -exec bash -c 'echo "$0" ; true' {} \; -o -quit \)
```

will list everything in current dir

```
find . -name '*'   \( -exec bash -c 'echo "$0" ; false' {} \; -o -quit \)
```

will list 1st item found (.) and stop

The commands being executed on the found paths here are

```
echo "$0" ; true # echoes path and succeeds / returns true
```

and

```
echo "$0" ; false  # echoes path and fails / returns false
```

The expressions being evaluated by find are

```
-exec bash -c 'echo "$0" ; true/false' {} \;
```

and

```
-quit
```

-o is logical OR (short-circuiting)

You need \( and \) so the shell doesn't attempt to evaluate the contents before passing everything to find:

```
find . -name '*'   '(' -exec bash -c 'echo "$0" ; true' {} \; -o -quit ')'
```

and

```
find . -name '*'   '(' -exec bash -c 'echo "$0" ; false' {} \; -o -quit ')'
```

give the same results as the \( \) versions above.

find interprets "`( <expression> -o -quit )`" as `(expr || stop)` so the first time expr fails the whole process stops.

**NB**
There does not appear to be any way to pass the/a failing exit code back to find's caller which renders the functionality (-exec {} etc) near useless for scripting purposes.